# Xcode 4.3: duplicated connections of an IBOutlet

Tags: xcode, connection, storyboard, iboutlet

I am learning Stanford CS193p course with Xcode 4.3.3. I think the screenshot below is pretty much self-explaining. But i will describe the problem with words anyway.

I control-drag a UILabel from storyboard to corresponding implementation file to make the IBOutlet @property. Then I see two connections displayed when clicking the filled circle in the left side of the editor where shows line numbers. I don't know how to delete it.

Moreover, I see only ONE connection in storyboard's connections inspector of the UIlabel.

More weird, when I try to set the UILabel's text inside the setter of a public preperty, it fails to update the label's text:

```
 -(void) setQuestion:(NSString *)question
 {
     _question = question;
     self.questionLabel.text = question;
     NSLog(@"The quesion is %@",question);
     NSLog(@"The quesion label text is %@",self.questionLabel.text);
 }
```

I use two NSLog to debug and get the following. It shows the NSString *question is @"What do you want your label to say?", yet the self.questionLabel.text is null. The value assign fails. I suspect this relate to the duplicated connections thing mentioned above.

> 2012-07-29 04:03:53.817 Kitchen Sink[18628:f803] The quesion is What
>   do you want your label to say?
>   2012-07-29 04:03:53.820 Kitchen
>   Sink[18628:f803] The quesion label text is (null)

The following is the screenshot showing the duplicated connections. I am probably missing something obvious, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stalk this up to Xcode storyboard wonkiness.

First, try a clean of the project and a re-build.

Should you still have that problem, manually define the @property without dragging from the AskerViewController view to the AskerViewController implementation (.m) file by doing the following.

Cut that IBOutlet @property line in the interface section of the implementation (.m) file for AskerViewController. Click the label in storyboard. Disconnect any binding that label to the AskerViewController. Clean the project. Then, paste back in the property, and control-drag from the label to the view controller orb at the bottom of the AskerViewController view in your storyboard file.

Comment: I relaunch Xcode, and the duplicated connection goes away by itself. Like you said it's wonkiness of storyboard. Not sure the relaunch would work next time.

Comment: But the assign failure persists. Any thought?

Comment: Hmm, are you using the `strong` keyword instead of `weak` within your @property options? Try switching to `strong`. It seems as though your UILabel reference is not being retained (although, that problem shouldn't exist, `weak` should work).

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I put up a new post here, please go check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713036/fail-to-assign-value-from-a-to-b-in-xcode#comment15538475_11713036