# Fail to assign value from A to B in Xcode

Tags: xcode, variable-assignment

I encounter a strange thing while coding in Xcode 4.3. The nature of problem is described in the title. I mentioned this together with a storyboard connection problem in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704316/xcode-4-3-duplicated-connections-of-an-iboutlet/11706414#11706414). The connection problem seems to go away at least for now. But the value assign problem persists. So I put it up as a new post.

```
-(void) setQuestion:(NSString *)question
    {
        _question = question;
        self.questionLabel.text = question;
        NSLog(@"The quesion is %@",question);
        NSLog(@"The quesion label text is %@",self.questionLabel.text);
    }
```

The result of the NSLog:

```
2012-07-29 04:03:53.817 Kitchen Sink[18628:f803] The quesion is What do you want your label to say? 
2012-07-29 04:03:53.820 Kitchen Sink[18628:f803] The quesion label text is (null)
```

Any thought?

Comment: Is questionLabel initialized? In Cocoa, you can do this on an uninitialized object, without a crash (depending on your compiler settings). Check the debugger output when it runs, because you do get warnings.

Comment: My thought is the same as above.  You can verify it by using `NSLog(@"The label is %@",self.questionLabel);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Ludvig and Mills. I add a line in viewDidLoad and problem solved. But the NSLog result is interesting.

I add this in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.questionLabel.text = self.question;
    ...
}
```

And I put up `NSLog(@"The label is %@",self.questionLabel);`  It shows the following:

```
2012-07-30 06:08:59.066 Kitchen Sink[21285:f803] The quesion is What do you want your label to say?
2012-07-30 06:08:59.068 Kitchen Sink[21285:f803] The quesion label text is (null)
2012-07-30 06:08:59.069 Kitchen Sink[21285:f803] The label is (null)
```

Why the label is still null? But `self.questionLabel.text` do change this time.